# Python Requests + Marketo REST API

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, anaconda, marketo

I am trying to talk to my Marketo Instance using Jupyter (Anaconda) and Requests package. I'm OK with creating the auth token, but getting stuck on making the actual call to the endpoint.

```
host = "https://my_mtko_instance.com"    
leadId = "13000000"
endpoint = "/rest/v1/lead/" + leadId + ".json"
auth_token =  "?access_token=" + mkto_token
getLead = requests.get(host+endpoint+leadId+auth_token)
print(host+endpoint+auth_token)
getLead.json()
```

I get a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Interestingly, I'm able to click the URL from print() and that takes me to a JSON looking response in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in how you assemble the url for the get request.

Please note, that the correct format of the endpoint is:
`https://<mkto_instance>.mktorest.com/rest/v1/lead/{leadId}.json`
However, with the `host+endpoint+leadId+auth_token` format you insert the `leadId` variable twice, as the `endpoint` variable already contains it.

Change the call to `requests.get(host+endpoint+auth_token)` and it should work fine.